# When `rw` tactic in Lean completes the proof?

Tags: lean

I'm learning Theorem proving with Lean in [Natural number game](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/xena/natural_number_game/), and I have difficulty in understanding the behavior of `rw` tactic.

In [Level 1/17 in Inequality world](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/xena/natural_number_game/?world=10&level=1), I wrote the following code:

```
use 1,
rw add_comm,
```

Then Lean completes the proof. Here I've not used `refl` tactic. On the other hand, in [Level 2/17 in Inequality world](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/xena/natural_number_game/?world=10&level=2), a similar code

```
use 0,
rw add_zero,
```

doesn't complete the proof. I suspected that the following code would work:

```
use 0,
symmetry,
rw add_zero,
```

but this code again doesn't complete the proof; I needed to use `refl` tactic in these cases. How should I understand the difference   of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a bug in NNG; the `rw` tactic in normal Lean always tries (a weak version of) `refl` after you finish all your rewrites, but this behaviour was disabled in NNG because it's not great for teaching. However, turning this behaviour off isn't easy, and sometimes it will slip through the cracks.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the situation. I wrote a modified `rw` tactic for NNG because the game does not teach definitional equality, and so goals like `x = x + 0` were being closed after a rewrite in earlier versions, which confused users (x = x + 0 is definitionally true so can be proved by `refl` even though this is not advertised at all in the game). I'm surprised the goal is closed after the rewrite, it is probably a bug in my hacked rw tactic.